# How can you separate a specific part of a website body in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

here is the body:

```
"kind": "youtube#searchResult",
    "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/uHwvNpWXbfDW_4Wj8a7WcvZxdKo\"",
     "id": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "MXVWCuahiD4"
},
```

its a youtube api's output from a channel called Camodo Gaming, anyway i need to get the part that says "videoID": "[id]". I don't know how i should split the body. Google cant answer this question.
Here is my current code(using a npm-module request):

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?
part=snippet&channelId=UCC6ulNJ-KDoIa3VI2gcvQpA&maxResults=1&order=date&type=video&key={token}', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 

  var str = body
  //how can i split the string?
  var split = str.split() // ?
  console.log(split)
});
```

**EDIT:**
here is the whole body:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/-0EYfTuxeWYgCGHPclJlgnzp8FU\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "regionCode": "FI",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 858,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/jlYGCUcC2rF87jrQ8VYhA_RRByk\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "paXZZap3bpo"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-03-23T11:00:05.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCC6ulNJ-KDoIa3VI2gcvQpA",
    "title": "MASSIVE HURRICANE IN THE  ZOMBIE APOCALYPSE! - GTA 5 Mod Gameplay - Zombie Multiplayer Roleplay",
"description": "MASSIVE HURRICANE IN THE ZOMBIE APOCALYPSE! - GTA 5 Mod Gameplay - Zombie Multiplayer Roleplay Welcome to Camodo Gaming's Let's Play of GTA 5 Zombie Apocalypse. We are trying out a zombie...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/paXZZap3bpo/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/paXZZap3bpo/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/paXZZap3bpo/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Camodo Gaming",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. If `response` is already parsed, you can simply use `response.id.videoId` (use `console.log(response)` to see the object's structure)

Comment: Agree, or else try `var obj = JSON.parse(body);`. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: the response is not parsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result comes in JSON format, which can be easily parsed into a real JS object, from where you can just call `.videoId` to get the videoId.

```js
var request = require('request');
request('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCC6ulNJ-KDoIa3VI2gcvQpA&maxResults=1&order=date&type=video&key={token}', function(error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error);
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
  var json = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(json);
  console.log(json.items[0].id.videoId);
});
```

Comment: I don't know the complete body, could it be that '.videoId' is part of something more deep in the JSON? Or maybe your request fails overall and body is undefined in the first place

Comment: i can send you the whole body in a sec

Comment: its in the question now

Comment: Then it has to be json.items[0].id.videoId. Edited in the answer as well